# Will Android BroadcastReceivers still receive intents if the process housing the receiver is killed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm curious if a broadcast receiver specified by a pending intent sent to another process will fire even if the app is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If an app publishes a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) via the `<receiver>` tag in its AndroidManifest.xml, and something kills the app's process, an incoming intent will (re)start the process.

On the other hand, if the app registers a receiver in its `Activity.onResume()` method, it should unregister it in `Activity.onPause()`.

See [Receiver Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) and [Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ProcessLifecycle).

Comment: Is this process restarting behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: I added doc links on Receiver Lifecycle and Process Lifecycle.

Comment: I pored over those carefully this afternoon. I don't see where they mention the behavior you describe above.

Comment: That's kind of the point of receivers. Also see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html "Broadcast receivers enable applications to receive intents ... even when other components of the application are not running." That phrasing isn't as crisp as "even when the app isn't running."

Comment: I was looking for something that was crystal clear. I should probably just test it.

Comment: I don't have a crystal clear doc reference, but consider http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html . Android sends the intent ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED to all relevant registered receivers at a time when no apps are running. It sends ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED to an app just after shutting it down and installing a new version.

Comment: Ok. Your evidence based argument (and the test I just completed) convinced me. Marking your answer as correct!